# Is it possible for an SVG element to have a width transition?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300"
    shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">
    <rect width="160" height="160" rx="0" ry="0" transform="matrix(.707107 0.707107-.707107 0.707107 150 36.862915)"
        fill="none" stroke="#000" />
    <line x1="-15" y1="0" x2="15" y2="0" transform="translate(135 150)" fill="none" stroke="#3f5787"
        stroke-width="3" />
    <line x1="-15" y1="0" x2="15" y2="0" transform="translate(165 150)" fill="none" stroke="#3f5787"
        stroke-width="3" />
    <line x1="-15" y1="0" x2="15" y2="0" transform="matrix(0 1-1 0 150 135)" fill="none" stroke="#3f5787"
        stroke-width="3" />
    <line x1="-15" y1="0" x2="15" y2="0" transform="matrix(0 1-1 0 150 165)" fill="none" stroke="#3f5787"
        stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

I'm dynamically modifying the value of the `x1` attribute of each `line` element inside the SVG, using Vue.js, as it changes the width of that line.

However, it would be way better if there was a CSS transition when that width changed, but I can't get it to work as the it's the value of the `x1` attribute that is changing and not the width of that element.

Comment: Wrap the SVG in a div, make the SVG 100% wide and adjust the width of the div. Just as you would an image. Simpler all round.

Comment: To be clear, I need to resize the individual `line` elements of the SVG and not the SVG itself.

Comment: Use SMIL to animate the values.